# Write a Python dictionary inside a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I would like to write a Python dictionary inside a CSV file.
My code is:

```
import csv
cluster = {}

cluster['cluster0'] = [0,'value1','value2','value3']

cluster['cluster1'] = [1,'value1','value2','value3']

csvfile2 = "//home/tom/Desktop/cluster.csv"

with open(csvfile2, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(cluster)
```

But instead of getting:

```
0,value1,value2,value3
1,value1,value2,value3
```

I have inside my CSV file:

```
c,l,u,s,t,e,r,0
c,l,u,s,t,e,r,1
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: You should use collections.OrderedDict if you want to preserve the order of your rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the dictionary name, you should call the `.values()` method

```
with open(csvfile2, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(cluster.values())
```

As an example:

```
d = {1: [1,2,3], 2: [4,5,6]}

>>> d.keys()
[1, 2]

>>> d.values()
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```